# Why does a method that uses an ArrayList but returns a primitive type require the method name to include "static"?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, compiler-errors, static

This program works but I'm not sure why the methods that are using an `ArrayList` must include `static` in the method header. Just for background, the program takes in a text file, reads it and saves its contents into an `ArrayList<Game>` (games). The user enters in the file name and the team name and the program outputs how many games that particular team has played, how many games it has won and how many it has lost.

The .csv that it reads has this format:

```
ENCE,Vitality,9,16
ENCE,Vitality,16,12
etc..
```

All four methods below, one method returning an `ArrayList` and the other three returning `int`s, will not work unless I put in the key word `static` in the method header. If I only write `public ArrayList<Game>` or `public int` for the methods, they will not work.

Is it the case that anytime that an `Arraylist` is being passed into a method that that means the method header must always include `static`? And why is this the case?

Here's the working code:

```
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SportStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("File: ");
        String file = scan.nextLine();
    
        ArrayList<Game> record = getGame(file); //After method returns the list of 
        objects, it is copied over to another list.

        System.out.println("Team: ");
        String team = scan.nextLine(); 
    
        //These methods return how many games a team played, has won and has lost.
        int gamesPlayed = getGamesPlayed(record, team);
        int gamesWon = getGamesWon(record, team);
        int gamesLost = getGamesLost(record, team);
    
        System.out.println("Games: " + gamesPlayed);
        System.out.println("Wins: " + gamesWon);
        System.out.println("Losses: " + gamesLost);

    }

    //This method takes in the file name given by user and saves file details into 
    a list of objects.
    **public static** ArrayList<Game> getGame(String file){
        ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
    
        try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(Paths.get(file))){
            while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                String input = reader.nextLine();
                String[] parts = input.split(",");
                String homeTeam = parts[0];
                String visitingTeam = parts[1];
                int homePoints = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
                int visitingPoints = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);
            
                games.add(new Game(homeTeam, visitingTeam, homePoints, 
                visitingPoints));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: File " + file + " not found.");
        }
    
        return games;
    }

    **public static int** getGamesPlayed(ArrayList<Game> record, String team){
        int gamesPlayed = 0;
        for(Game game: record){
            if (game.getHomeTeam().equals(team) || 
            game.getVisitngTeam().equals(team)){
                gamesPlayed++;
            }
        }
    
        return gamesPlayed;
    }

    **public static int** getGamesWon(ArrayList<Game> record, String team){
        int gamesWon = 0;
        for(Game game: record){
            if (game.getHomeTeam().equals(team) || 
            game.getVisitngTeam().equals(team)){
                if(game.getHomeTeam().equals(team) && game.getHomePoints() > 
                game.getVisitingPoints()){
                    gamesWon++;
                }
                if(game.getVisitngTeam().equals(team) && game.getVisitingPoints() > 
                game.getHomePoints()){
                    gamesWon++;
                }
            }
        }
    
        return gamesWon;
    }

    **public static int** getGamesLost(ArrayList<Game> record, String team){
        int gamesLost = 0;
        for(Game game: record){
            if (game.getHomeTeam().equals(team) || 
            game.getVisitngTeam().equals(team)){
                if(game.getHomeTeam().equals(team) && game.getHomePoints() < 
                game.getVisitingPoints()){
                    gamesLost++;
                }
                if(game.getVisitngTeam().equals(team) && game.getVisitingPoints() < 
                game.getHomePoints()){
                    gamesLost++;
                }
            }
        }
    
        return gamesLost;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is unrelated to the argument list or the return type. You are using these methods in a static context (i.e., you are **not** calling them on a specific instance), therefore they must be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

static just means that it is not part of the object you create from a class. It is independent from the objects/instances you create. You could say it just relates with/is part of the class and is not a feature.